# Play Asset Delivery not working when fetching pdfs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf, assets

So I have this app, but its to big for the play store because it has lots of pdfs, so I decided to use play asset delivery to retrieve the pdfs. I have done everything like it says in google docs, I have created an asset-package, changed everything in the manifest, build.gradle and build a bundle! But the play asset delivery just isn't working! I can't get my pdf files that are on the "pdfs->src->main->assets" !! Can someone please help me? Am I choosing the right package name?

[image]

My source code to retrieve the pdf is the following :

```
            mPDFView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdf);

    Context context = null;
    try {
        context = createPackageContext(getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = assetManager.open("A abóboda.pdf");
        mPDFView.fromStream(is).load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```